# Map View always center map on my location

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I use the following code to get my location when a user presses a button

```
 [mapview setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

and then the follwoing to center the map to te user's location

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation      
{
   [mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

My question is how to prevent the map from always centering on my location? I want to allow the user to pan the map.

Comment: How about removing the call in the delegate that centres the map? You've got it right there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it came in with iOS5, you can now drop the delegate stuff and just set the userTrackingMode of the MKMapView. Set it to MKUserTrackingModeFollow to make the make move along with the user and then when they start panning the map around it'll turn off the tracking mode automatically, you then just need to provide a button to turn it back on.

Comment: Not true.. it still recenter the map with the trackingmode technique

Comment: Yes true. It will keep recentering the map when tracking mode is turned on...until you interact with it (which disables the tracking mode). Which is exactly what the OP asked for and why it was accepted as the right answer.

Answer (score 6):

Center on the location only the first time you show the map.  Here is some pseudo code...

```
    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation      
    {

       if(shouldCenterLocation){
           [mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
           shouldCenterLocation = FALSE;

        }
        //do all your other stuff here
    }
```

shouldCenterLocation is a boolean flag that you can set to TRUE the first time the map is shown, then set it to FALSE until you exit the view (or any other condition you have for showing the center location).

edit: you can toggle the state of shouldCenterLocation in the same method that you handle the button press.

Comment: Remember that the first fix you get may not be very accurate, you might want to check the horizontal accuracy is good enough before you settle on it.

Answer (score 1):

On swift 3 I prefer use animated method:

```
mapView.setUserTrackingMode(.follow, animated: true)
```

but set property good worked:

```
mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
```