# MKPinAnnotationView heading

Tags: iphone, dictionary, mkannotationview, heading

In my app the MapView is dynamic and updating due to the Iphone direction like this:

```
CLLocationDirection  theHeading = ((locationManager.heading.trueHeading > 0) ?
                                   locationManager.heading.trueHeading :     locationManager.heading.magneticHeading);
[mapView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(theHeading))];
```

If the user opens the MKPinAnnotationView, i want this view also to respond to the iphone heading, so i  also used "setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation".

Every time a device heading is getting updated both the mapview and the PinAnnotationView are getting updated too.
The problem is that at the beginning it takes 3-4 turns(left and right) till their direction become steady and before it they kind of going "wild".
I hope i've explained it the right way

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't setting the map's `userTrackingMode` to "follow with heading" work for you instead of these manual transforms?

Comment: not really, because if i zoom or scroll the map it stops tracking.
Do you know some solution for this?

Comment: Give the user a button to "re-start" the tracking mode when they want to.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9640193/467105.

Comment: Thanks, but i need it to keep tracking all the time and not to set the view's center to the user's location